Use of quotation marks in parentheses when shortening a title
I work as an Urban Planner and write development applications which can be long documents that are professional but not necessarily standardized. A question has come up about shortening titles of documents in these documents and whether or not quotation marks are needed within parentheses. Here is an example:
The City of Whatever (“City”) is requesting a Property Line Adjustment to expand the Water Reservoirs site (“Reservoir Site”) located at 123 B Street ... A Water System Master Plan Amendment (“Water Plan”)
Is it necessary to have the quotation marks?
What about when noting an acronym for the first time:
The owners of Lot 2400 have signed a Purchase and Sale Agreement (PSA)?
Thank you for any help!

Unless you're constrained to adhere to a specific style guide that explicitly covers this point, it's entirely up to you. My impression is that most more recent legal documents today don't include such unnecessary quote marks (look at some online credit card agreement texts, for example). But I think this is a matter of legal / corporate conventions, not the use of English as such.

Quotes seem fitting when thing is known as "A":  The Water System Master Plan Amendment (“Water Plan”). No quotes when you define your own X for thing: Purchase and Sale Agreement (PSA).

This depends on the style guide. While perhaps not the exact same type of writing, a blog about contract drafting cites A Manual of Style for Contract Drafting (MSCD):

MSCD 5.37 says “place in quotation marks and state in bold any defined term that’s being defined in a defined-term parenthetical.”

While this differs from general-purpose style guides like Chicago (which give recommendations for parenthetical abbreviations), it's because this type of writing has its own conventions:

And using quotation marks not only makes sense, it’s standard among U.S. practitioners.


In general, urban planning follows the APA style guide but I couldn't find anything on their website about this.
